# How to create logic app with name which deleted before

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I created a logic app which name is 'lga' in tenantA, but I want to create a new logic app which name is also 'lga' in tenant B. I didn't also create 'lga' logic app  in tenant B when deleting logic app in tenant A.

The name was not used in tenant B after waitting a few of days. but this name can be used in tenant A. It seems the name is linked with tenant A. Do someone know how to use this name in tenant B.

Answer (score 0):

Since the end of 2022, Azure has started to make use of name reservations when it comes to web apps such as logic app standard. This means that after a resource has been deleted from the **Tenant A**, the Logic App name will not be available for other tenants for a period of time.

If you want to release the reservation, the only way seems to be to open a support ticket.

Read more about it in [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/name-reservation-on-app-service-for-web-apps-and-app-service/ba-p/3675100).